# Using an AdHocWorkspace results in "The language 'C#' is not supported."

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn

Using the RC2 of Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces in VS2015, this code throws an exception:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(...);
var workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
var newRoot = Simplifier.Expand(tree.GetRoot(),
    compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree, false),
    workspace,
    n => true,
    true,
    CancellationToken.None);
```

The exception message is "The language 'C#' is not supported."

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a reference to the [C# Workspaces NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces/1.0.0-rc2).

This will copy the C# DLLs to your output, and let Roslyn's MEF scanner see the language services.

Comment: I do have that package referenced; in fact, it is the only Roslyn package I pulled in to make sure that all of the dependencies lined.

Comment: @AethonInvictus: Is `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll` in your output directory? Do you see it in Debug, Modules?

Comment: There are three different assemblies: *.CSharp.dll, *.CSharp.Workspaces.dll, *.Workspaces.dll ( * = Microsoft.CodeAnalysis).

As @SLaks recommended, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll was what I needed.