# Roslyn throws The language 'C#' is not supported

Tags: c#, roslyn

I have created a *class library project* and did some processing and also used Roslyn to generate code.

I use the library in a WPF GUI application as a reference.

These are the NuGet packages:

[image]

Build shows no error, however when I use the following code:

```
private static void GetGenerator()
{
  workspace = new AdhocWorkspace();
  generator = SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(workspace, LanguageNames.CSharp);
}
```

I get an exception:

> "The language 'C#' is not supported."

```
   at: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.HostWorkspaceServices.GetLanguageServices(String languageName)
   at: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Host.Mef.MefWorkspaceServices.GetLanguageServices(String languageName)
   at: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editing.SyntaxGenerator.GetGenerator(Workspace workspace, String language)
```

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c03febde-cf6d-478e-ac01-99102eb07f1b/the-language-c-is-not-supported-bug-on-newcompilationunitformat?forum=roslyn) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601934/using-an-adhocworkspace-results-in-the-language-c-is-not-supported), I have to copy the CodeAnalysis files locally and add the necessary references. They are there, yet the error occurs.

Is this still a bug that wasn't fixed in the last year?

What else should I do?

Comment: Do you have a dependency on the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces package?

Comment: @svick Yes, I do, I updated my initial post with the NuGet packages list.

Comment: IMO this is a [problem with MsBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1469)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to add the **`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`** package to both the *class library project* AND the *referencing project* as well.

Answer (score 36):

Most likely it's because you don't reference `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` in your code, i.e. you never use a type or method in this dll, so MSBuild thinks it's not needed (see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816769/dependent-dll-is-not-getting-copied-to-the-build-output-folder-in-visual-studio) question).

So what you could do is e.g. add the following line somewhere in your *class library project*:

```
var _ = typeof(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Formatting.CSharpFormattingOptions);
```

Then MSBuild should copy `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll` over and everything should be fine. No need to reference the NuGet packages from all the other projects.

Comment: In my case I was loading a solution via Roslyn in a standalone commandline app and all projects failed to load because I didn't have that package referenced in my app altogether. Adding a nuget reference fixed it.

Comment: This would be a better solution than the accepted answer but isn't doable for all dlls. For example, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features.dll which is needed for code completion for C#, does not expose a single public type, so nothing to hold on to. The alternative is either a manual post-build event to copy the file, or the accepted answer of adding the Nuget packages to both the library and the referencing project. Yuck. The post-build action actually seems preferable to me.

Comment: Or option 3) add the required dlls as linked files into the referencing project and put "Copy to output directory" to "copy if newer".

Comment: This answer helped, sortof, In my case I added `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` to 2 projects but I'm guessing it failed on the main one and I didn't notice the add not being performed for both.